# How to Save HasAndBelongsToMany (habtm) data when empty in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many, save, cakephp-2.3

I have a `hasAndBelongsToMany` association between `Node` and `NodeTag`.

My save works great when at least one is selected, but - if there is a previous association, and they try to save with none selected, my `habtm` table doesn't get updated, since it's not getting anything passed for `NodeTag`.

(I'm not sure if this is because I'm using javascript and custom buttons, or if the default CakePHP checkboxes do the same thing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my Controller, before the save, I added this:

```
if(!isset($this->request->data['NodeTag'])) {
    $this->request->data['NodeTag'][0] = array();
}
```

This makes it so if I wasn't sending any `NodeTag` data, I now pass an empty array, and it updates the `habtm` table so that this Node no longer has any rows for NodeTags.

**Note:**  Notice the array structure:  `['NodeTag'][0] = array();`

Answer (score 0):

I was actually using your solution until it dawned on me that it is possible to achieve this with the Formhelper. Setting the hiddenField option to true (`'hiddenField' => true`), will force the submission of an empty array. Doing that saves you the trouble of checking once more in the controller.

I do not know how you could achieve it with javascript, but the default checkboxes have the functionality.

Comment: `hiddenField` is `true` by default, so setting it to true does nothing.  Yes, it doesn't change it from submitting, but what it DOES submit (by default) doesn't update the HABTM data.